# Validating against a schema with DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, validation

I'm attempting to validate some XML input against a XSD schema. The parser works, but when I hook in a schema, I get the exception below. I've validated the test input with an external validator, so I've eliminated that. Does anyone know how to setup a builder to validate this way?

Here's the builder setup code.

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
final SchemaFactory sf = 
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

factory.setValidating(true);  
final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(
        getClass().getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_PATH)));
factory.setSchema(schema);

builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler());
```

And here's the error I'm getting.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:236)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:172)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:382)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:316)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:779)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1794)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:250)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:292)
    at com.casenet.external.mockclaims.ResponseScriptBuilder.build(ResponseScriptBuilder.java:54)
    at com.casenet.external.mockclaims.ResponseScriptBuilderTest.buildFull(ResponseScriptBuilderTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:932)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:868)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:110)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
```

Comment: Note that Schema is immutable and thread-safe: you don't have to load it multiple times, just cache it in a static field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to call:

```
setValidating(true);
```

If you do the following:

```
documentBuilderFactory.setSchema(schema);
```

From the [setSchema(Schema) javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29):

> This processing will take effect even
>   if the isValidating() method returns
>   false.